# How can I generate Ant targets?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I want to be able to generate a number of Ant targets something like this:

```
<property name="grunt_tasks" value="jsp,css,js,img" />
<foreach list="${grunt_tasks}" param="task">
    <target name="${task}">
        <exec executable="grunt" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="${task}" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</foreach>
```

allowing me to run `ant jsp` or `ant js`.

However, this code fails because a target tag cannot be placed in a foreach tag.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you might add targets on the fly.  Here's one suggestion:

```
<property name="mybuild" value="mybuild.xml" />

<property name="grunt_tasks" value="jsp,css,js,img" />

<echo message="&lt;project&gt;" file="${mybuild}" />
<for list="${grunt_tasks}" param="task">
    <sequential>
    <echo file="${mybuild}" append="yes"><![CDATA[
    <target name="@{task}">
        <exec executable="grunt" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="@{task}" />
        </exec>
    </target>
    ]]></echo>
    </sequential>
</for>
<echo message="&lt;/project&gt;" file="${mybuild}" append="yes"/>

<import file="${mybuild}" />
```

Explanation:

- Use the antcontrib [`<for>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) in preference to `<foreach>`, else you have to have a separate target for the body of the loop.
- Create a second buildfile, here called `mybuild.xml`, to contain your targets.
- The buildfile content has to be within a `<project>` element.
- [Import](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) the buildfile.

You can then invoke the on-the-fly targets in the way you wish.

You might alternatively use a [`<script>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) to create the targets if you prefer, which would remove the need for the separate buildfile and import, something like this:

```
<for list="${grunt_tasks}" param="task">
    <sequential>
    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
        importClass(org.apache.tools.ant.Target);

        var exec = project.createTask( "exec" );
        exec.setExecutable( "grunt" );
        exec.setFailonerror( true );
        var arg = exec.createArg( );
        arg.setValue( "@{task}" );

        var target = new Target();
        target.addTask( exec );
        target.setName( "@{task}" );

        project.addOrReplaceTarget( target );
    ]]></script>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: I'm not so crazy about generating another xml file to accomplish this. I think I'd rather just suffer some repetition in my build.xml.

i've taken a look at the script task but have failed to find any documentation that would indicate how i'd go about creating targets.

Comment: @Matthew Added a script approach.  The documentation for using the API is the source itself.  [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.9.4/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Execute.java?av=f) is one way to peruse.

Comment: A couple of things I learned along the way -  
  
load('nashorn:mozilla_compat.js'); // since i'm on Java 8 and using importClass, in other words Rhino compatibility  

exec.createArg( ).setValue( "--target_env=" + target_env ); // for some reason ant properties are available to js directly although the task param isn't.

ug, formatting isn't my strong suit